# Надпись смещается относительно заголовка

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Надпись с датой `side-date` смещается в левую сторону, хотя должна быть вверху относительно заголовка. Пробовал `flex-direction`, но не работает

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@400;700&display=swap');
body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin: 0px;
}

.side-bar {
  width: 272px;
  background-color: #f4f7f6;
}

.side-news-header-title {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.side-news-header-title::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 66px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: #e1d9bd;
  margin-top: 12px;
  margin-bottom: 29px;
}

.side-img {
  display: block;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.side-block {
  display: flex;
  width: 272;
  margin-bottom: 22px;
}

.side-title {
  font-size: 14px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-top: 0;
}

.side-date {}

.side-date-title {
  font-family: 12px;
  opacity: 50%;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<aside class="side-bar">
  <div class="side-news-header">
    <h3 class="side-news-header-title">Новые посты</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="side-block">
    <img class="side-img" src="https://netology-code.github.io/html-2-diploma/sources/images/last-post1.jpg">
    <div class="side-date">
      <span class="side-date-title">14 июня 2019</span>
    </div>
    <h4 class="side-title">10 мест, ради которых стоит проснуться</h4>
  </div>
</aside>
```

Answer (score 0):

не изобретайте велосипед, просто разбейте то, что слева, то, что справа, то, что сверху, то, что снизу, много универсальности тоже не очень хорошо

```css
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@400;700&display=swap');
    body {
      font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
      font-weight: 400;
      margin: 0px;
    }

    .side-bar {
      width: 272px;
      background-color: #f4f7f6;
    }

    .side-news-header-title {
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 14px;
    }

    .side-news-header-title::after {
      content: "";
      display: block;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      width: 66px;
      height: 3px;
      background-color: #e1d9bd;
      margin-top: 12px;
      margin-bottom: 29px;
    }

    .side-img {
      display: block;
      width: 70px;
      height: 70px;
      margin-right: 20px;
    }

    .side-block {
      display: flex;
      width: 272;
      margin-bottom: 22px;
    }

    .side-title {
      font-size: 14px;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      margin-top: 0;
    }

    .side-date {
       padding-right: 10px;
    }

    .side-date-title {
      font-family: 12px;
      opacity: 50%;
      font-weight: 400;
      font-size: 12px;
    }
```

```html
    <aside class="side-bar">
      <div class="side-news-header">
        <h3 class="side-news-header-title">Новые посты</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="side-block">
        <img class="side-img" src="https://netology-code.github.io/html-2-diploma/sources/images/last-post1.jpg">
        <div class="side-date">
          <span class="side-date-title">14 июня 2019</span>
          <h4 class="side-title">10 мест, ради которых стоит проснуться</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
    </aside>
```